# Is there a software to edit video with rotate scree option?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, video, video-editing

I have a video recorded with my mobile. But its tilted to 90 degrees anti-clockwise. Is there a way to view it normal way (by rotating it clockwise 90 degrees) by using some video editing tool?

I tried to record desktop screen, rotating desktop screen (using intel desktop graphic properties) by clockwise 90 degrees but it didn't work, I couldn't play the file at all in rotated mode.

Please let me know if its possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[VLC](http://www.videolan.org/) also has a 'rotate' filter so you can view the file as intended, and it can also be used to save the video again.

Comment: oh is it ?? well I didn't observe vlc carefully then :) ok, I try it and reach you back :) thanks regards :)

Answer (score 2):

[Avidemux](http://avidemux.org/) has a filter that will allow you to rotate a video in increments of 90°.

Comment: thanks. :) ok.I try it and reach back to you :) thanks regards.